# Unable to edit file geodatabase: How do I fix it?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, file-geodatabase

I have different geodatabase for different project. When I start projectA.mxd which connects to projectA.gdb, I cannot create and edit feature class inside. However, when I start projectB.mxd, I can create and edit projectA.gdb.

Why???? How can I fix it?

I am using ArcMap 10.1.

Comment: But I can add feature class in arccatalog.

Comment: ArcGIS 10.1 is ancient, and Retired., so there aren't many who could reproduce your environment. Please do not comment on your own post, especially comments which make the problem less clear. Please [Edit] the question to specify exactly how you attempt feature class creation, and the exact error message that results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be worth a shot:

- Open a second instance of ArcMap with a new blank map document.
- Copy and paste (or drag and drop) all of the layers (or layer groups) from the old map document to the new map document.
- Save the new map document.
- Close the old map document.
- Now see if it works from the new map document.

MXDs tend to store a lot of old cruft in them, even if its related to layers that are no longer in the map.  They can also become corrupt in various ways on occaions.  The steps above are a general recommendation that is worth trying in many situations in order to end up with a new map document that has none of the (possibly corrupt, or otherwise bad) cruft from the old map document, but still has all the layers.  It may miss other document settings however (eg, layout config).

Comment: that works! Cant believe it.

Comment: As a thought experiment, even though your problem is solved, maybe try to run MXD doctor (small program shipped with an installation of ArcGIS) on your seemingly corrupted MXD.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal for a geodatabase to have a lock while you're accessing it, such as when the geodatabase is connected to an open mxd, so you won't be able to edit the geodatabase in ArcCatalog while it's open in ArcMap. If you want to edit the records stored in the geodatabase, you can use the Editor toolbar (Customize, Toolbars, Editor and select Start Editing), but if you want to edit the feature dataset or feature class name etc., you need to close other windows with a connection to that geodatabase, such as the MXD for this project.

[Esri's documentation on geodatabase locking.](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/file-geodatabases-and-locking.htm)

Per Esri's [technical documentation](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000002474), you may receive this error when trying to create a feature class within a feature dataset which has some item in use in ArcMap. Remove other layers related to that feature dataset in ArcMap and try again, or close ArcMap and create the feature class in ArcCatalog.

> Error Message When attempting to create a new feature class within an
>   existing feature dataset using ArcCatalog, you may receive the
>   following error message:
>
> Cannot create a feature class in the selected feature dataset because
>   the feature dataset is in use by another application/user. Lock
>   request conflicts with an established lock [layer].
>
> Cause This error occurs when a layer from the feature dataset is being
>   accessed in ArcMap at the same time a new feature class is being
>   created inside the feature dataset using ArcCatalog.

Comment: I am not using separate ArcCatalog. I am just using the catalog inside ArcMap. Suppose I can create feature class inside?

Comment: This Esri resource goes into further detail on geodatabase locking. I'll also add it to the answer above. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/file-geodatabases-and-locking.htm.  What are you trying to edit with the geodatabase?

Comment: I am trying to create a new feature within ArcMap. I right click the geodatabase and then click new, then feature class. But, it said it is locked.

Comment: However, when I closed it and open another project which does not link to the database, I can create features.

Comment: [As of 10.3 at least you can use that method](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/databases/create-a-feature-class-in-a-database-in-arcgis.htm) (creating feature class within the Catalog window within ArcMap) but I don't have 10.1 to test. It may be a version difference. Can you do this with any of your geodatabases?

Comment: I guess may be the mxd file has some problem. I have checked other MXD which connects to the same database. I can create feature class. But, that particular MXD cannot.

Comment: Found [Esri technical documentation on this error](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000002474) - it sounds like the the feature dataset you're trying to create the feature class in is in use in ArcMap.